# Error use preg_match get value have string and number

Tags: php

```
$text = '
<p>Author</p>
<p>Availability</p>
BeautyBeauty11055981
<p><a href="APPNDX_SortValuesArticle.html#salesrank">salesrank</a>                                                                                                  </p>BooksBooks1000';
```

I need get all value have string and number (BeautyBeauty11055981, BooksBooks1000). But result error

```
if ( preg_match ( '/^[a-Z][0-9]$/', $text, $matches ) )
{
   print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qcJ0Ff/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex [`/[A-Za-z]+\d+/`](https://regex101.com/r/PpizOl/3) (has to be used with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to match all occurrences).

- `[A-Za-z]+` matches the first part of the key e.g. `BeautyBeauty` or `BooksBooks`.
- `\d+` matches the last part of the key e.g. `11055981` or `1000`.

Full code:

```
$text = '
<p>Author</p>
<p>Availability</p>
BeautyBeauty11055981
<p><a href="APPNDX_SortValuesArticle.html#salesrank">salesrank</a></p>BooksBooks1000';

if (preg_match_all('/[A-Za-z]+[\d]+/', $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]); // Returns: Array ( [0] => BeautyBeauty11055981 [1] => BooksBooks1000 )
}
```